# Take a screenshot of a particular area in Delphi 7

Tags: screenshot, delphi-7

I have a panel in the form delphi that contains pictures, labels and others. I need to take screenshots in the panel area.
How can I perform this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a panel named Panel1 to be screenshot, a button named Button1 to do the screen shoot, and Image1 to display the screenshot, here is simple code you can use:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  bitmap: TBitmap;
  dc: HDC;
begin
  bitmap := TBitmap.Create();
  try
    dc := GetDC(Panel1.Handle);
    try
      bitmap.Width := Panel1.Width;
      bitmap.Height := Panel1.Height;
      BitBlt(
        bitmap.Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height,
        dc, 0, 0,
        SRCCOPY
      );

      // copy the screenshot to an image
      Image1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(bitmap);

      // copy the screenshot to the clipboard
      Clipboard.Assign(bitmap); 

      // save the screenshot to a file
      bitmap.SaveToFile('c:\filename.bmp');

    finally
      ReleaseDC(panel1.Handle, dc);
    end;
  finally
    bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Terima Kasih om benar" sesuai yang diinginkan

Comment: Sip sip. Sama-sama.